# Visual Studio project references not recognized. Forced to remove then re-add the project reference

Tags: c#, reference, project

I'm having an issue with my solution finding project references after I pull the source code from TFS. After I get latest, I'll compile my solution and it will complain that it cannot find classes in other projects. These have been added as project references. When I check the references folder of the project that has the issue, the project reference is there and appears to be correct (properties look correct and I do no have the warning tooltip over the reference in the solution explorer) The only way I have been able to fix this is by removing the project reference then re-adding. As soon as I do that the errors go away even before I compile and all is well. I did some searching but was not able to find anyone with this specific issue. It seems to happen whenever someone adds in a new project into our solution then we get latest to get their changes. This will also happen on everyone's machine except the person who added the project. Once one of us goes through the steps of re-adding the references and commits those changes, it works for the rest of the team. All of use are adding project references like normal.

Here are the details of my development environment:

- Windows 7
- Visual Studio 2015 (v14.0.2317.0 D14REL)
- C# .NET 4.6
- TFS 2015
- Resharper 10.0.1

Comment: When someone adds a project are they referencing these classes at a location specific to their machine? That would not exist on the machines of others?

Comment: You should reference from a generic location such as the public assemblies folder. Then when a build is attempted all refs are found by the compiler.

Comment: you need to archive the csproj and sln files after adding a new project

Comment: suo and other user related files should not be checked in, these can cause the problem

Comment: Terry, they are project references to project included in the overall solution.

Comment: Dexion, I doubled checked, we do not have any sou or other usre files that are included in our source control.

Answer (score 1):

I too faced similiar issue today. And now I understood the problem.... under 4.5 framework related project1 is referring superior framework 4.5.2 related project2.

So I did made them both as same and my solution started working..

Not sure whether same will work for you or not. Please verify on your solution as well.